# onmouseover and onmouseout not work

Tags: javascript, php, onmouseover

My `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` functions are not working.

Here is my PHP file.
I wont to add medals and info of medals,but i cannoct add :/
Please help me.

Sory for my bad english.
**I have a lot medals,but here is the first**

```
    <h2>Medalje</h2></div></div>

<?php
    $medalje_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM medalje WHERE kome='$idmember' ORDER BY type ASC");
    if(mysql_num_rows($medalje_query)==0){echo "Korisnik nema Medalja";}
    while($medalje_row = mysql_fetch_array($medalje_query)){
        $id     = $medalje_row['id'];
        $type   = $medalje_row['type'];
            if($type=='1'){$link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:;" onmouseover="prikazimis ("Administrator");" onmouseout="sakrijmis();" <img src=""> 
         <img src=""></span></a>';}
        elseif($type=='2'){$link_medalje = '<span id="user-award-20" class="user-award"><img src="" alt="6y.png" data-tooltip="EXAMPLE TEXT" title=""></span>';}                                                    // vip
        elseif($type=='3'){$link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:;" class="tooltip"><img src="" alt="1_generacija" /><span class="tip">EXAMPLE TEXT</span></a>';}    // prva generacija clanova
        elseif($type=='4'){$link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:;" class="tooltip"><img src="" alt="izabrani_forumas" /><span class="tip">EXAMPLE TEXT</span></a>';}                        // izabrani forumas
        elseif($type=='5'){$link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:;" class="tooltip"><img src="" alt="gramatika" /><span class="tip">EXAMPLE TEXT</span></a>';}   // clanovi koji paze na pravopis i gramatiku
        elseif($type=='6'){$link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:;" class="tooltip"><img src="" alt="spammer" /><span class="tip">EXAMPLE TEXT</span></a>';}         // spammer
        elseif($type=='7'){$link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:;" class="tooltip"><img src="" alt="donator" /><span class="tip">EXAMPLE TEXT</span></a>';}     // donator
        elseif($type=='8'){$link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:;" class="tooltip"><img src="" alt="server_admin" /><span class="tip">EXAMPLE TEXT</span></a>';}    // server admin
        elseif($type=='9'){$link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:;" class="tooltip"><img src="" alt="" /><span class="tip">EXAMPLE TEXT</span></a>';}                    // 25 tema na forumu
        elseif($type=='10'){$link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:;" class="tooltip"><img src="" alt="" /><span class="tip"></span></a>';}                   // 300 postova na forumu
        elseif($type=='11'){$link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:;" class="tooltip"><img src="" alt="" /><span class="tip"></span></a>';}                   // 25 vijesti
        elseif($login_id<100) { $link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:;" class="tooltip"><img src="" alt="1_generacija" /><span class="tip">EXAMPLE TEXT</span></a>'; }
        echo $link_medalje;
        /*if ($profil_id<100) { echo '<a href="javascript:;" class="tooltip"><img src="" alt="1_generacija" /><span class="tip">EXAMPLE TEXT</span></a>'; }*/
    }
?>
```

Comment: provided code its not enough to help you. Provide console output you have, provide output html you get as for JS its important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax errors. Try to use this

```
if($type=='1'){$link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="prikazimis(\'Administrator\');" onmouseout="sakrijmis();"><img src=""></a>';}
```

Comment: Please update the code you have tried or are you getting any error in cosole. Check that please

Comment: You were having still syntax issue. please check my updated answer and paste as it is there and check again

Answer (score 0):

`$link_medalje` should be like this

```
$link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="prikazimis(\'Administrator\');" onmouseout="sakrijmis();" ><img src="..."></a>';
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

```
if($type=='1')
{
    $link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="prikazimis(\'Administrator\');" onmouseout="sakrijmis();" <img src=""></a>';
}
elseif($type=='2')
{
    $link_medalje = '<span id="user-award-20" class="user-award"><img src="" alt="6y.png" data-tooltip="EXAMPLE TEXT" title=""></span>';
}                                                    // vip
elseif($type=='3')
{
    $link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tooltip"><img src="" alt="1_generacija" /><span class="tip">EXAMPLE TEXT</span></a>';
}    // prva generacija clanova
elseif($type=='4')
{
    $link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tooltip"><img src="" alt="izabrani_forumas" /><span class="tip">EXAMPLE TEXT</span></a>';
}   // izabrani forumas
elseif($type=='5')
{
    $link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tooltip"><img src="" alt="gramatika" /><span class="tip">EXAMPLE TEXT</span></a>';
}   // clanovi koji paze na pravopis i gramatiku
elseif($type=='6')
{
    $link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tooltip"><img src="" alt="spammer" /><span class="tip">EXAMPLE TEXT</span></a>';
}  // spammer
elseif($type=='7')
{
    $link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tooltip"><img src="" alt="donator" /><span class="tip">EXAMPLE TEXT</span></a>';
} // donator
elseif($type=='8')
{
    $link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tooltip"><img src="" alt="server_admin" /><span class="tip">EXAMPLE TEXT</span></a>';
}    // server admin
elseif($type=='9')
{
    $link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tooltip"><img src="" alt="" /><span class="tip">EXAMPLE TEXT</span></a>';
}   // 25 tema na forumu
elseif($type=='10')
{
    $link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tooltip"><img src="" alt="" /><span class="tip"></span></a>';
}     // 300 postova na forumu
elseif($type=='11')
{
    $link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tooltip"><img src="" alt="" /><span class="tip"></span></a>';
}    // 25 vijesti
elseif($login_id<100)
{ 
    $link_medalje = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tooltip"><img src="" alt="1_generacija" /><span class="tip">EXAMPLE TEXT</span></a>'; 
}

echo $link_medalje;
```

Comment: @Haris have you echo this variable or not? because its the code line is ok. also check your functions applying on mouseover and mouseout

Comment: no i don't have echo...
elseif($type=='2'){$link_medalje =
elseif($type=='3'){$link_medalje =
etc...